# Eclipse outgoing changes asterisk icon

Tags: eclipse

I am upgrading my eclipse to new version and I forgot how did I enable this "Asterisk" icon next to the projects which have an outgoing change. This is really helpful instead of a small ">" icon next to the project.

I tried looking around in preferences but wasn't able to find it. Can experts way in here. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What is your source control system?  CVS, Subversion, or Git?

Comment: CVS and I am using eclipse Juno 4.3M4 version. I believe this is an eclipse feature independent of CVS used.

Comment: Check your Label Decorations preferences.  Then check your CVS and Team Preferences again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its under Team-> CVS-> Label decorations -> Icon Decorations-> Outgoing Changes

[image]